# XML data format for a query on Nextcloud OCS

Tags: node.js, xml, express, curl, nextcloud

The problem is about getting a direct download link to a Netcloud file.

Documentation :

> To obtain a direct link:
> POST /ocs/v2.php/apps/dav/api/v1/direct
> With the fileId in the body (so fileId=42 for example).

I want to POST this URL with Nodes.js. What is the XML (I guess) format to set "fileId=42" in the body of my request ?
Everything I try returns me
"Invalid query, please check the syntax. API specifications are here:[http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services."](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services.%22) but noway there to get the format.
Samething with curl, no syntax is working.

In a more generic way what is the XML (I guess) format when querying the OCS API?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question:

1. At last I suceeded in making it work with curl, single/double quotes in Windows was the problem, fixed using "{" escape character.
2. This told me this was not about OCS data format itself as data is to be sent as it, ie "fieldId=42"
3. Switching from NojesJs/https lib to Axios fixed the problem. Probably some content-type header, however I tried 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' which fits with the data to send.